# Use polyfills of Node.js built-in modules in React-Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, webpack, polyfills

Some Node.js packages I'd like to use in a React-Native app have dependencies on Node.js' built-in modules like `url`, `http` and `crypto`. These packages are designed to be packaged with Webpack, and take advantage of [Webpack's polyfills](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser).

I've added the required polyfills to my root `package.json` file but I'm still seeing errors like `Unable to resolve module 'crypto'` in my app.

How do I tell the React-Native packager to use polyfills instead of trying to load the built-in Node.js modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those interested the best solution I've found is to use the [mvayngrib/rn-nodeify](https://github.com/mvayngrib/rn-nodeify) Node.js package, which is a hack to allow react-native projects to use node core modules, and npm modules that use them.